# nginx modifying the content in compressed response

Tags: curl, nginx, browser, gzip, gunzip

In our project we have a problem where we have to edit the response content that is served through ngnix. For the uncompressed responses we are able to do it through **sub_filter**  module of ngnix, but for the compressed response we have to uncompress the response and edit teh response for that we are using the **gunzip** module.

The problem is when we use the gunzip the response content that is render through ** curl** command contains the changes that we made , but when the same thing is rendered through browser the response does not contain our changes. Can any one explain me what might be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably browser is adding `Accept-Encoding: gzip` header so nginx is returning the gzipped response and not activating the gunzip module.